# BOBJ 4.1 Use values from two not joined tables in one pre-defined condition

Tags: business-objects

I use a number of pre-defined conditions to compare the Date field from Trade table against GETDATE() function to work out the trades for this month, this year, previous year etc.

Now I need to create an additional table, where I will have a set of dates representing the start and the end dates for reporting periods, e.g. the start and end dates of current year reporting, the start and the end dates for previous year reporting etc.

This additional table and Trade table are not joined. In fact the additional table is not linked to anything.

I need to create a new set of pre-defined conditions where Date from Trade table will be compared from the values from the new dates table, i.e. I would like the new conditions to look like the following

```
Trade.Date < ReportingDates.CurrentYearEndDate 
AND 
Trade.Date > ReportingDates.CurrentYearStartDate
```

The condition validates fine, but unfortunately I get the "The query cannot run because it contains incompatible objects. (IES 00008)" error" when I try to execute the condition.

Comment: Does `ReportingDates` contain only a single row?

Comment: @Joe Yes, and always will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subselects in the predefined condition like:

```
trade.date between (select currentyearstartdate from reportingdates)
               and (select currentyearenddate from reportingdates)
```

Since `reportingdates` is not actually joined to anything, it does not need to be in the universe structure.  This does have one disadvantage -- it's not obvious from the list of tables that it is actually needed in the universe.

Alternatively, you can create a derived table that joins `trade` and `reportingdates` as a cartesian product.  The derived table would include all columns from both tables, so your condition would simply be (assuming the derived table is named `DT`):

```
dt.date between dt.currentyearstartdate and dt.currentyearenddate
```

The downside to *this* approach is that `reportingdates` is included in *all* queries, whether it's needed or not, and the SQL can be a little harder to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joe. Your hint about the sub-queries was very useful. Didn't know that you can use them in the pre-defined conditions.